# How to Push value in array of object based on condition and avoid pushing duplicates in Angular 14

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, angular14

Below is my code, here I want to push the `subModule` object into the `selectedPieces` array if `submodule.active` is `true` and if it is not present inside the `selectedPieces` array. But in my code, it is inserting values multiple times after inserting two values. The `Pieces` object is as below and `activateClass` is my method on which if I will click I will get the piece object.

```
Pieces = {
  pieceId: 1,
  img: '../../../../assets/img/piece.PNG',
  letter: 'O',
  active: false
}

activateClass(subModule){
    subModule.active = !subModule.active;  
    subModule.activeli = !subModule.activeli; 
    if(this.selectedPieces.length == 0 && subModule.active == true){
      this.selectedPieces.push(subModule);
    }
    else{
    for(let i=0;i< this.selectedPieces.length; i++){
      if(subModule.active == true && subModule.pieceId !== this.selectedPieces[i].pieceId){
        this.selectedPieces.push(subModule);
      }
      if(subModule.active == false && subModule.pieceId == this.selectedPieces[i].pieceId){
        this.selectedPieces.splice(i);
      }
    }
    }
   
    console.log(this.selectedPieces);
  }
```

Comment: pieceId and pieceid are different. Please check casing. Also splice method need to have second parameter if you want to delete that only one element.

Comment: For the first 2 time it is inserting the values correctly. After that for 3rd value it is inserting it twice for 4th value it is inserting it 4times duplicate values. Similarly splice is also not working

Comment: That's expected because you are pushing inside loop. So for every item in the array it checks the condition and push supplied element.

Comment: Please help me with the correct code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
activateClass(subModule){
  subModule.active = !subModule.active;  
  subModule.activeli = !subModule.activeli; 
  if (this.selectedPieces.length === 0 && subModule.active === true){
    this.selectedPieces.push(subModule);
  } else {
    let index = this.selectedPieces.findIndex((piece) => piece.pieceId === subModule.pieceId);
    if (subModule.active === true && index === -1) {
      this.selectedPieces.push(subModule);
    }
    if (subModule.active === false && index >= 0) {
      this.selectedPieces.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }

  console.log(this.selectedPieces);
}
```

Comment: When only 2 values are left in the array it is not removing the values from selectedPieces. One value always remains in the array

Comment: @triptitiwari Can you try this updated answer?